# How do you set the default selection using Ember.Select in Grouped mode?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using the latest version of Ember that contains the Select view modification to provide option groups. It's working perfectly except that I can't seem to set the default value.

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/csprocket777/Ja77Z/

Given the fiddle above, how would I set the default value?

I've inserted the code in the jsFiddle here:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding=filterValues
        optionLabelPath="content.label"
        optionValuePath="content.id"
        optionGroupPath="group"
        selectionBinding=selectedFilterOption
    }}
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    selectedFilterOption: Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "File Type", 
                id: "urltype",
                group: "By Attributes"
            }),
    filterValues:function(){
        var ret = [
            Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "Unfiltered", 
                id: "id",
                group: "By Attributes"
            }),
            Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "Alphabetical", 
                id: "label",
                group: "By Attributes"
            }),
            Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "File Type", 
                id: "urltype",
                group: "By Attributes"
            }),
            Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "Title", 
                id: "title",
                group: "By Value"
            }),
            Ember.Object.create({ 
                label: "Order", 
                id: "order",
                group: "By Value"
            })
        ];

        return ret;
    }.property()
});
```

Comment: I guess this might be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to set up `value` for `Ember.Select`, for example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding=filterValues
  optionLabelPath="content.label"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionGroupPath="group"
  selectionBinding=selectedFilterOption  
  value="title"
}}
</script>
```

It can be a `valueBinding` if you prefer.

Comment: That worked. I also discovered that if you have the selectionBinding set to the object that you want as your default valueBinding, it won't work. May just be a quirk in what I'm doing.

Comment: I also updated this jsFiddle in case anyone needs it. http://jsfiddle.net/Ja77Z/2/

Comment: Maybe your selectionBinding is a string, and should be integer - I wasted couple of hours until I noticed that was the problem :) I know this is just guessing, but it might be the cause of the problem, so it's worth checking.